# SPARQL Lexical error Encountered: "%"

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, owl, rdfs

```
String queryString2 = "PREFIX service: <http://www.usa.gov/services/> "
        + " PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> "
        + " PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "
        + " PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> "
        + " SELECT ?entity ?categoryname ?servicename ?description WHERE { "
        + "{ "
        + " ?entity a owl:Class; rdfs:subClassOf %s; rdfs:label ?categoryname. "
        + " OPTIONAL {?entity rdfs:description ?description}. "
        + "} "
        + "UNION "
        + " { "
        + "?entity rdf:type %s; service:name ?servicename. "
        + " OPTIONAL {?entity service:description ?description}. "
        + " } " + "}";

Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString2);
```

Hi All,

When running above query with Jena API, I'm getting following error. Can someone please help me on this.

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Lexical error at line 1, column 315.  Encountered: "%" (37), after : ""
```

Comment: The query parser doesn't lie. Could you show where you format in %s? Have you tried `String.format` first to get rid of the %s's?

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Answer (score 3):

According to the SPARQL 1.1 Recommendation, variables in SPARQL begin with question marks (or dollar signs), but not percent signs:

> #### [4.1.3 Syntax for Query Variables](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#QSynVariables)
>
> A query variable is marked by the use of either "?" or "$"; the "?" or
>   "$" is not part of the variable name. In a query, $abc and ?abc
>   identify the same variable. The [possible names](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rVARNAME) for variables are given
>   in the [SPARQL grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#grammar).

As a general note about constructing strings that will be parsed as something (in this case, SPARQL queries, but this holds in general), it's good practice to add newlines `\n` to them, so that it's easier to recognize where parse errors happen.  If you had added newlines to your query, you'd have received an error about line seven,

```
?entity a owl:Class; rdfs:subClassOf %s; rdfs:label ?categoryname.
```

which would have made this easier to detect.  For instance, if you copy this query:

```
PREFIX service: <http://www.usa.gov/services/> 
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
SELECT ?entity ?categoryname ?servicename ?description WHERE { 
  { 
    ?entity a owl:Class; rdfs:subClassOf %s; rdfs:label ?categoryname. 
    OPTIONAL {?entity rdfs:description ?description}. 
  } 
  UNION 
  { 
    ?entity rdf:type %s; service:name ?servicename. 
    OPTIONAL {?entity service:description ?description}. 
  }
}
```

into the [validator at sparql.org](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html), you'll get the more useful output:

> Input:
>
> ```
>   1 PREFIX service: <http://www.usa.gov/services/> 
>   2 PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
>   3 PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
>   4 PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
>   5 SELECT ?entity ?categoryname ?servicename ?description WHERE { 
>   6   { 
>   7     ?entity a owl:Class; rdfs:subClassOf %s; rdfs:label ?categoryname. 
>   8     OPTIONAL {?entity rdfs:description ?description}. 
>   9   } 
>  10   UNION 
>  11   { 
>  12     ?entity rdf:type %s; service:name ?servicename. 
>  13     OPTIONAL {?entity service:description ?description}. 
>  14   }
>  15 }
> ```
>
> Syntax error:
>
> ```
> Lexical error at line 7, column 42.  Encountered: "%" (37), after : ""
> ```

If you were trying to use a value that would be ignored in the query results, simply not specifying it in the `select` list of variables is sufficient.  If you really don't want to even bind it to a variable in the query, you could use a blank node to simply say `?entity` is an `rdfs:subClassOf` *something*:

```
?entity a owl:Class; rdfs:subClassOf []; rdfs:label ?categoryname.
```

If, on the other hand, you planned on replacing `%s` with some particular resource, then you should consider using Jena's [ParameterizedSparqlString](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ParameterizedSparqlString.html), which have been discussed in

- [get latitude and longitude of a place dbpedia](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16737653/1281433)
- [Parameterized SPARQL query with JENA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9729659/1281433)